# what is the default color scheme for sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, color-scheme

I've changed the color scheme on sublime text 2 and I really hate the colors it changed to.

So what is the name of the default settings? Because I want to change it back to the standard.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The default Color Schema for ST2 is Monokai

Comment: Right in the middle, where nobody would ever reach by trial and error, with a name nobody would ever think might be the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Color Scheme for Sublime 3

```
Preferences -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme - Default -> Monokai
```